# Estimation the mean parameter

Tags: estimation, mle

How can I estimate the mean of the normal distribution, while it is an increasing function?

In other word, ascending the mean is a key requirement.

Comment: Is this a coding question or a math question?

Comment: It is a math question Jason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/